# Yup schema: How to add new line in error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, yup

```
matches(
  /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/,
  `Must contain 8 characters, At least one (1) uppercase, one (1) lowercase, one (1) Number and one special case character`
)
```

and

```
matches(
  /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/,
  `Must contain 8 characters,\n At least one (1) uppercase, one (1) lowercase, one (1) Number\n and one special case character`
)
```

How do I set a new line on the matches error message?

cause I already tried the `\n` and `<br/>` but it doesn't work.

What I'm trying to do is like this:

```
Must contain 8 characters,
At least one (1) uppercase, one (1) lowercase, one (1) Number 
and one special case character
```

the output should be like this ^

but on my side instead it will set it new line.
the output is like this:

`Must contain 8 characters, At least one (1) uppercase, one (1) lowercase, one (1) Number and one special case character`

it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) will make the lines broken at new line characters or `<br/>`:

```
.matches(
  /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/,
  `Must contain 8 characters,\n At least one (1) uppercase, one (1) lowercase, one (1) Number\n and one special case character`
),
```

```js
{errors.firstName && (
  <div style={{ color: "red", whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>
    {errors.firstName.message}
  </div>
)}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66730451/how-to-set-new-line-on-matches]